# How can I use Views in a Watchface for Wear OS?

Tags: android, wear-os

When I want to insert a view in my watchface  (class: CanvasWatchFaceService), findViewById is not resolved. I need it for AnimatedDrawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on the subject a few years back: [Layout-based Watch Faces for Android Wear](https://sterlingudell.wordpress.com/2015/05/10/layout-based-watch-faces-for-android-wear/). Because it was written in 2015, a few details have changed - like the name of the OS, and steps for creating the initial project in Android Studio - but the general approach still works.

Also, here's a more recent sample where I used the technique specifically for animations: https://github.com/StringMon/io18watchface